# Trying to connect to rabbitMQ in c# but getting a BrokerUnreachableException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Hi I'm having trouble connecting to rabbitMQ server, after following the tutorial on their site to here's my code below.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

        string message = "Hello World!";
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Can you connect to rabbitMQ directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BrokerUnreachableException` means that the client can't reach the server.

Check if the server is actually up and running, or if you have some firewall configuration.

There are several posts about `BrokerUnreachableException`, follow for example [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/Fk6ofV5gAIs) about that